# AngularJS : how to make object in objects to call subsequent http calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am a completely angular newbee, and I have a question about angular ng-repeat tags.

Here I have a list of devices and it is about to iterate each device in the html.

The question is, if each device will start to call a separate api, for example, like /devices/:device_id/get_some_thing_else using the given device_id from each device. How do i construct my angular page with which ng tag ?

I want the page to display a list of devices first before having each device to call a separate API.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you are asking some question, it's always good to  write some code, because you are increasing chance that other user will better understand and see where is the problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The ng-repeat does not actually make any API calls. It just binds to an array

Say for example you had this variable in your JS file

```
$scope.devices = [{name: "device One"}, {name: "device Two"}, {name: "device Three"}];
```

then in your HTML you had

```
<div ng-repeat="device in devices">
<h1>{{device.name}}</h1>
</div>
```

when the page was rendered it would show

```
device One
device Two
device Three
```

where each line was wrapped in an H1 tag and also in a DIV tag

You are responsible in your javascript file for specifying how the data gets into $scope.devices, usually through a factory.

Whenever the data in $scope.devices changes so will the corresponding HTML.